# Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1(1)

Tags: c++, xcode, directory, breakpoints

I'm trying to do a small project and I came over a breakpoint issue. I had it previously on char dirname[256] when I had a char holding it. However, after I removed the char it changed the breakpoint to the cout, which I never had before. I fairly new in c++ somewhat in-depth explanations would be nice. Thank you.

Code: C++

```
//  main.cpp
//  File Creator and Sorter
//
//  Created by yared yohannes on 12/15/21.
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main(){
    char dirname[256];
    
    cout << "What is the name of the file: ";
    cin >> dirname;
    
    DIR *d = opendir(dirname);
    if( ! d)
    { std:: cout << "ERROR: Please provide a valid directory path.\n";   }
}
```

Comment: @SercanSebetçi Thanks bro got it to work with the page you sent me. Gonna read over it to understand debugging.

Comment: Every time I come back to this I'm embarrassed by it. However, I am impressed by my code, not gonna lie. Especially since I literally googled "basic c++ main images" 10 seconds before writing it.

        Some quick explanation for anyone here that doesn't wanna read the link, breakpoint is a debugging tool that stops the program when it gets to that line. I think in most IDEs now u have to run it in debugging mode though, but it's really useful since humans are slower.

        Actually helped me figure out issues in my logic a few times, especially in mobile app development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is related to using XCode editor rather than coding. I recommend reading [this article](https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/xcode-debugging-with-breakpoints-for-beginners-5b0d0a39d711).